# Markdown syntax for table is not working properly over outlook mail in power automate approval action

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, approval-process

I am using "Start and Wait for an approval" action in power automate. Within the body I am putting Markdown syntax table of the product details. When user sees the approval request email, it renders the table properly in Web outlook and teams, but does not render properly in Outlook mail box.

Could any one please guide me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using Markdown which is not supported in Outlook desktop:

[image]

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/approvals-markdown-support#client-support

Comment: Hello Julie,
You are correct. But if you can see the 'Table' should support in Outlook desktop, although it is not..Any idea on this?

Comment: If possible, please provide detailed format of the table.